# How to aggregate mongoose collection?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my mongoose model I have an invoiceHeader and invoiceLine collection both relating to account object. 
In a view I want to display the total invoiceAmount for the account.
In SQL something like select sum(amount) from invoiceHeader group by account.
How can i achieve similar with nodeJS and mongoose?

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate

Comment: I have read the documentation but don't understand how to implement? I would like to have a virtual property with the sum

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `amount` is the property that you want to sum on, it would be like:

```
InvoiceHeaderModel.aggregate({
  $match: {
    account: '<Account_ID>'
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    total: {
      $sum: "$amount"
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    total: 1
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  // res contains the result
});
```

The `$match` operator is used to match certain documents. The `$group` operator is used to group the documents. The `$project` operator is used to select certain fields from the documents.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation however res contains the result but console.log(res) returns [object Object] how can I get the $sum value?

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));`. I'm not sure if its a subarray that the result format comes in or its an object which contains the key `total` so accessing to would be `res.total`